# How to resolve 'cannot pass parameter by reference' error in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

Here's my code:

```
$stmt = $conn->mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO photos (CaseNo, ImageName, CaptureTime, UploadTime) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
$stmt->bind_param('isss', $caseno, $index.'.'.$extension, date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

I have tried this also:

```
$stmt = $conn->mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO photos (CaseNo, ImageName, CaptureTime, UploadTime) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
$captureTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$uploadTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$stmt->bind_param('isss', $caseno, $index.'.'.$extension, $captureTime, $uploadTime);
```

I am getting the error:

> Fatal error:** Cannot pass parameter 3 by reference in **...file path...line #

Please note that **CaptureTime** and **UploadeTime** have datatype ***date***. And ignore the fact that I am passing the value of 3rd and 4th parameter same.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: reference for you: this issue has similar problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105373/php-error-cannot-pass-parameter-2-by-reference

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Change

```
$stmt->bind_param('isss', $caseno, $index.'.'.$extension, $captureTime, $uploadTime);
```

to

```
$isss = 'isss';
$indexExtention = $index.'.'.$extension
$stmt->bind_param($isss, $caseno, $indexExtention , $captureTime, $uploadTime);
```

I believe you have to pass variables rather than a string.

Or you could use `bindvalue()` instead of `bindparam()` if you're using PDO.

Comment: Are you sure mysqli statement supports **bindvalue** function()? In the mysqli manaul on php.net, I do not see that function.

Comment: Ahh, no. Only PDO seems to support it. I thought MySQLi did too.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you need to cast it to string?

```
...$extension, (string) $captureTime, (string) $uploadTime);
```