# PHP error: "Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference"

Tags: php, mysqli

I just need help on this PHP error which I do not quite understand:

> Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /web/stud/openup/inactivatesession.php on line 13

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

include('connect.php');

$createDate = mktime(0,0,0,09,05,date("Y"));
$selectedDate =  date('d-m-Y', ($createDate));

$sql = "UPDATE Session SET Active = ? WHERE DATE_FORMAT(SessionDate,'%Y-%m-%d' ) <= ?";
$update = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$update->bind_param("is", 0, $selectedDate);  //LINE 13
$update->execute();

?>
```

What does this error mean? How can this error be fixed?

Comment: reference for you: this issue has similar problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287581/how-to-resolve-cannot-pass-parameter-by-reference-error-in-php#autocomment44785441

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The error means that the 2nd argument is expected to be a **reference to a variable**.

Since you are not handing a **variable** but an **integer of value 0**, it generates said error.

To circumvent this do:

```
$a = 0;
$update->bind_param("is", $a, $selectedDate);  //LINE 13
```

In case you want to understand what is happening, as opposed to just fixing your `Fatal error`, read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: PHP can be so weird sometimes.

Comment: Really funny, because the error message seems to indicate exactly the opposite :-) It said "Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference" and I was like "But I am not passing it as reference so what is the problem?"

Answer (score 4):

First,you shouldn't use `DATE_FORMAT` when you want to compare date because `DATE_FORMAT` changes it to string *not date anymore*,

```
UPDATE Session 
SET Active = ? 
WHERE SessionDate <= ?
```

Second, store the value first on a variable and pass it on the paramater

```
$createDate = mktime(0,0,0,09,05,date("Y"));
$selectedDate =  date('d-m-Y', ($createDate));
$active = 0;
$sql = "UPDATE Session SET Active = ? WHERE SessionDate <= ?";                                         
$update = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$update->bind_param("is", $active, $selectedDate);  
$update->execute();
```