# Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference - uuid PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to insert `UUID()` together with my `INSERT` query.

```
$handle->beginTransaction();
// Define query
$query = "INSERT INTO users (users_uuid, type_id) VALUES (:uuid, :type_id)";
// Prepare statement
$stmt = $handle->prepare($query);
// Bind parameters
$stmt->bindParam(':uuid',"SELECT UUID()",PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':type_id',1,PDO::PARAM_INT);
// Execute query
$stmt->execute();
$handle->commit();
```

This query return this error **Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference ... on line 51**. And it points to the line `$stmt->bindParam(':uuid',"SELECT UUID()",PDO::PARAM_STR);`

What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP error: "Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105373/php-error-cannot-pass-parameter-2-by-reference)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The second argument to `bindParam` is passed by reference and should be a variable. You are directly passing the values which is not allowed.

Place `UUID()` directly in the query because if it is bound as a parameter, it would be placed in the query as a quoted string and will not be evaluated to a UUID value.

You can place the `1` directly in the query too. Or assign `1` to a variable and give that variable as the second argument while binding the parameter `:type_id`.

```
$type_id = 1;
$stmt->bindParam(':type_id', $type_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Wait I'm lost, pardon my technical terms insufficiency. But can you show what you mean in code?

Comment: It does works now, as you suggested, however I am receving a `NULL` return from `var_dump($stmt->execute())`

Comment: Try `var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());` after execution and check the error message.

Comment: Ahh seen it, thanks it works now! Added question (if okay) what if the generate UUID collides, is there any way it will regenerate/attempt again? I'm looking on this `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax, but not sure if this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have an error when I use `errorInfo()` but none with `getMessage()` even if I have an attribute set `$handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: It is highly unlikely that generated UUIDs will collide. There are many questions regarding possiblity of UUID collision for more details.

Comment: You should be getting an exception in this case, unless you have put them inside `try/catch`. If you have them in `try/catch` catching `PDOException $e`, try `echo $e->getMessage();die;` inside `catch`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to bind it in this case, simply include it in your query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (users_uuid, type_id) VALUES (UUID(), :type_id)";
```

..then bind `:type_id` as you already are.

Comment: Even if I did that still it returs the same error, I even replace `SELECT UUID()` with `789EF1A1-0063-44D4-B300-84CDD8D875A5` as string but no luck.

Comment: But did you remove `$stmt->bindParam(':uuid',"SELECT UUID()",PDO::PARAM_STR);`?

Comment: Yeah I did. Leaving `$stmt->bindParam(':type_id',1,PDO::PARAM_INT);` the only one left.

Comment: If you bind as a parameter, it will be escaped and will end up as a literal string. What you want to do is have `UUID()` directly in your query. No need for a placeholder for that.

Answer (score 0):

your
    INSERT INTO users (users_uuid, type_id) VALUES (SELECT UUID(), 1)

is not a valid mysql query

try to get uuid() first, then insert the value into your users table

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing a value, use this:

```
$type_id = 1;
$stmt->bindValue(':type_id', $type_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

If you are binding a parameter (where you pass a reference to the variable), then do this:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':type_id', $type_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// now you can update $type_id, since it is a reference, and execute multiple times:
foreach($id as $i){
    $type_id = $i;
    $stmt->execute();
}
```