# Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in %$name%

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $query = "
         SELECT 
             id,
             overskrift,
             tekst,
             detaljer,
             varenummer,
             lager,
             vegt,
             pris,
             billede,
             fallow_id
         FROM davidsen_vare
         WHERE 
             overskrift LIKE ? OR varenummer  LIKE ?)
         LIMIT 30";

    $Statement = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
    $Statement->bind_param("ss","%$sogning%","%$sogning%");   //error here
    $Statement->execute();
    $Statement->bind_result($id,$overskrift,$tekst,$detaljer,$varenummer,$lager,$vegt,$pris,$billede,$fallow_id);
```

Can some one please help

Comment: are the parameters integers or strings?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105373/php-error-cannot-pass-parameter-2-by-reference

Comment: its strings but it will not work even if i only do it with 1 ? and only 1 "s",%$sogning%

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP error: "Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105373/php-error-cannot-pass-parameter-2-by-reference)

Answer (score 2):

```
 $query = "
SELECT 

    id,
    overskrift,
    tekst,
    detaljer,
    varenummer,
    lager,
    vegt,
    pris,
    billede,
    fallow_id
FROM davidsen_vare

WHERE 
( overskrift LIKE %?%
   OR varenummer  LIKE %?%)
   LIMIT 30";

    $Statement = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
   $Statement->bind_param("ss",$sogning,$sogning);
```

OR

```
 $query = "
SELECT 

    id,
    overskrift,
    tekst,
    detaljer,
    varenummer,
    lager,
    vegt,
    pris,
    billede,
    fallow_id
FROM davidsen_vare

WHERE 
( overskrift LIKE ?
   OR varenummer  LIKE ?)
   LIMIT 30";

    $Statement = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
    $Statement->bind_param("ss",'%'.$sogning.'%','%'.$sogning.'%');
```

Comment: when i do that i get this 
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in

Comment: $Statement->bind_param("ss",'%'.$sogning.'%','%'.$sogning.'%');  

give the same result as
$Statement->bind_param("ss",$sogning,$sogning);  
gave me

Comment: my friend help me out.. this is the answer

Comment: $search_phrase = '%'.$sogning.'%';             
        $Statement->bind_param("ss", $search_phrase, $search_phrase);