# Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Tags: php

The code:

```
final class SimpleEventManager {
    private $listeners = array();

    public function listen($event, $callable) {
        $this->listeners[$event][] = $callable;
    }

    public function fire($event, array $arguments = array()) {
        foreach ($this->listeners[$event] as $listener) {
            call_user_func_array($listener, $arguments);
        }
    }
}

$manager = new SimpleEventManager;
$manager->listen('sql', function($sql) {
    $sql .= " order by username desc";
});
$sql = "select * from users";
$manager->fire('sql', array($sql));
var_dump($sql); // is: select * from users
                // want: select * from users order by username desc
```

So basically i want my event listeners to be able to modify the arguments that come in. I've tried doing things like `array &$arguments = array()` but then I'm getting the `Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference` error.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Modify the function to *accept* the argument by reference.  `public function fire($event, &$arguments)`

Comment: Not the answer, but why are you calling foreach? `$this->listeners[$event]` isn't an array.

Comment: @cale_b I'm not sure what you mean, could you give a bigger code example? I've tried using `fire($event, &$arguments)` but then I get the same error at `$manager->fire('sql', array($sql))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP error: "Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105373/php-error-cannot-pass-parameter-2-by-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass it by reference because only variable may be passed by reference. The literal `array($sql)` is clearly not a variable.

That said, this isn't the problem.

In fact, there's a lot of problems, mostly because of `$sql` being "copied" so many times:

1. When creating the `array($sql)`
2. When calling `fire()` (due to not being passed by reference)
3. When calling the anonymous function (again, not being passed by reference)

First of all you need to define your array as a variable, such as `$arr = array(&$sql);`

Then keep your current "fix" of passing `&$arguments` by reference.

Finally, adjust your anonymous function to `function(&$sql)` to also work by reference.

All in all, this could be made a lot easier if your code weren't so convoluted ;)

Comment: Thanks that worked! How would you make this easier if I may ask?

Comment: Um... `$sql = "select * from users order by username desc";`?