# Issue with parameters on prepared statement

Tags: parameters

i'm trying to execute this query and i can't figure it out why it doesnt work, it returns:

Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

but i only have 1 parameter.

this is the code:

```
$GLOBALS['mysqli']->query("use ".$db."");
$stmt = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->prepare("SELECT * FROM item_template WHERE name LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s","'glyph of%'");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: I can't be sure, but with grids, where your parameter name is different, it thinks you are trying to pass "another".  I see bind_param refers to "s" - could it or should it be "name".  Please - just a suggestion - if I got it totally wrong.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the parameter should be a string that's why the "s", maybe i'm getting it wrong. should i remove the "s"?

Comment: Rather disregard my comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP error: "Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference".](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105373/php-error-cannot-pass-parameter-2-by-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
$stmt->bind_param("s","glyph of%");