# Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference error in php PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I am getting the error:
Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in.....

in this line...

```
$stmt1->bindParam(':value', $_SESSION['quantity'.$i] * $_SESSION['price'.$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

What is wrong with code above ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP error: "Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105373/php-error-cannot-pass-parameter-2-by-reference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It expects the second paramter to be a variable which can be passed by reference.  Assuming `$stmt1`is a PDO statement then, as the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) for bindparam say

> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference
>   and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is
>   called.

Your second param is an expression (`$_SESSION['quantity'.$i] * $_SESSION['price'.$i]`) not a variable.  Since you appear to want to evaluate the exptression now, I guess you should used `bindValue()` instead.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say it's the typical confusion between [PDO:bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and what you probably intended to use: [PDO:bindValue()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).

> `PDOStatement::bindParam`
>
> **Binds a PHP variable** to a corresponding named or question mark
>   placeholder in the SQL statement that was used to prepare the
>   statement. Unlike `PDOStatement::bindValue()`, the **variable is bound
>   as a reference** and will only be evaluated at the time that
>   `PDOStatement::execute()` is called.

> `PDOStatement::bindValue`
>
> **Binds a value** to a corresponding named or question mark placeholder in
>   the SQL statement that was used to prepare the statement.